# Criteria do grails

Tags: java, groovy, grails, criteria

Alguém por favor me diz o que significa esse ${result[0][0]} por que colocaram dois par de colchetes?

```
def criteria = Person.createCriteria()
def result = criteria.list {
projections {
    max('age')
    min('age')
  }
}
println "The maximum age is ${result[0][0]}"
println "The minimum age is ${result[0][1]}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme [o tutorial](http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-criteria) do qual o código em questão foi copiado, esse exemplo combina projeções e funções agregadas.

Projeções modificam o retorno da clausula select, de maneira que não faz sentido copiar o resultado para a entidade `Person`.

Na [documentação do GORM](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria) encontramos a seguinte passagem:

> Quando múltiplos campos são especificados na projeção, uma lista de valores será retornada. Caso contrário um único valor será retornado.

Pensando em Java, isso significa que o retorno da função será um `List<Object[]>` ou `List<Object>`.

No caso da sua função o `SELECT` será algo mais ou menos da forma:

```
SELECT max(age), min(age)
FROM Person;
```

Ou seja, sabemos que o resultado deve ter apenas uma linha com duas colunas representando respectivamente o retorno das duas funções agregadas (máximo e mínimo).

Como índices em Groovy começam do zero, acabamos com algo assim:

```
      COLUNA

L   *-----------------------------*
I   | indice  | 0       | 1       |
N   *---------*---------*---------*
H   | 0       | max(age)| min(age)|
A   *---------*---------*---------*
```

Ou seja, `result[0][0]`, retorna o máximo da primeira coluna. Já `result[0][1]` retorna o mínimo da segunda coluna. Ambos usam apenas a primeira (e única) linha.

Na prática porém dificilmente alguém vai propagar esse resultado tabular para as camadas superiores. Geralmente o resultado da consulta passa por um `ResultTransformer` ou uma transformação com `collect`, mas esse é um tópico para outra pergunta.